# Getting files in directory with *.tif file mask using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dos

So, I feel lame for asking this, but I'm kinda stumped. I'm trying to get a list of file in a directory that end in tif ... only tif ... not tiff. So, I did this in C# ...

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.tif", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

I would expect it to only return tif files, but that is not the case. I get tiff as well. I would think that if I supplied the mask ***.tif?*** that would get me both, but not the mask **.tif**. I tried it at a command prompt as well and I am getting both as well in DOS. Am I missing something here? This just seems wrong to me. I guess I could sanitize the results afterwards, but if I don't have to that would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx)

> When using the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern (for
>   example, "*.txt"), the matching behavior varies depending on the
>   length of the specified file extension. A searchPattern with a file
>   extension of **exactly three characters returns files with an extension
>   of three or more characters**, where the first three characters match
>   the file extension specified in the searchPattern. A searchPattern
>   with a file extension of one, two, or more than three characters
>   returns only files with extensions of exactly that length that match
>   the file extension specified in the searchPattern. **When using the
>   question mark wildcard character, this method returns only files that
>   match the specified file extension.** For example, given two files in a
>   directory, "file1.txt" and "file1.txtother", a search pattern of
>   "file?.txt" returns only the first file, while a search pattern of
>   "file*.txt" returns both files.

Comment: Sure enough. That is really screwy ... I think. Guess I'll just have to sanitize the results ... ugh!

Answer (score 1):

That's just how [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) works. From the manual:

> When using the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern, such as
>   "*.txt", the matching behavior when the extension is exactly three
>   characters long is different than when the extension is more or less
>   than three characters long. A searchPattern with a file extension of
>   exactly three characters returns files having an extension of three or
>   more characters, where the first three characters match the file
>   extension specified in the searchPattern.

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetFiles` internally uses [`FindFirstFile` function from Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

From the documentation of `FindFirstFile`:

> • The search includes the long and short file names.

A file that has long file name of `asd.tiff` will have a short file name like `asd~1.tif` and this is why it shows up in the results.

Answer (score 0):

More than three character extensions are matched **except** when the path is on a network share (or mapped drive).  For some reason the pattern only matches the long file name on remote drives.